Solving $\sqrt{3}\tan(x) < \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sin(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}$
When this came up, my math teacher told me to give up.
$$\sqrt{3}\tan(x) < \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sin(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}$$
I got as far as something like:
$$\sqrt{3}\sin^{2}(x) - \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2} - \sqrt{3}\cos^{2}(x) > 0$$
How do you continue/solve?

I'm pretty sure your first inequality is in the wrong direction

If you consider the function$$f(x)=\sqrt{3}\tan(x)- \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sin(2x)}{1 + \cos(2x)}$$ and let $\tan(x)=t$ you end with $$g(t)=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} t^2+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)  t-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ which has no real root and which is then always negative.

It's interesting that $\sqrt{3}=2\sin60^\circ$ and $1=2\cos60^\circ$. Unfortunately, this observation would really only be helpful if the problem had $2\sin2x$ and $2\cos2x$. ... Might there be a typo?

The original is right, but what i got might be wrong.

The proposed inequality is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3}\tan(x)(1 + \cos(2x)) > \sqrt{3} + \sin(2x) & \Longleftrightarrow 2\sqrt{3}\tan(x)\cos^{2}(x) > \sqrt{3} + \sin(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{3}\sin(2x) > \sqrt{3} + \sin(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin(2x)(\sqrt{3} - 1) > \sqrt{3}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin(2x) > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} - 1} > 1
\end{align*}
Hence it has no solutions.
Are you sure there is no typo?

There is no typo; we often get impossible equations as a test

Analysis: Both sides are periodic in $ -\pi \lt 2 x \lt \pi$. The $\tan $-term is negative for $ -\pi \lt 2 x \lt 0$ , the fraction positive because in the numerator  $\sqrt 3 \gt 1=\max |\sin|$. It follows that the relation is  the reverse as stated, confirmed  at small $ x \ge 0 $.
The denominator $1 + \cos(2x) = 2 \sin^2(x)$ is positive except at the zeros of the sine so it remains to show for $\sin (2 x) >0$
$$\sqrt{3} (\cos (2 x)+1) \tan (x)-\sin (2 x)<\sqrt{3}$$
trivially true after simplification
$$(\cos (2 x)+1) \tan (x)=2 \sin (x) \cos (x)=\sin (2 x)$$
$$\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \sin (2 x)<\sqrt{3}$$

Writing  $\tan x=t,$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt3+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x}-p\tan x=\dfrac{\sqrt3(1+t^2)+2t}2-pt=\dfrac{\sqrt3t^2-2t(p-1)+\sqrt3}2=\dfrac{t^2-2\cdot t\cdot\dfrac{(p-1)}{\sqrt3}+1}{\dfrac2{\sqrt3}}$$
$$t^2-2\cdot t\cdot\dfrac{(p-1)}{\sqrt3}+1=\left(t-\dfrac{p-1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1\ge1-\dfrac{(p-1)^2}3$$
Now $1-\dfrac{(p-1)^2}3$ will be $>0$ (which is a sufficient condition for $\dfrac{\sqrt3+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x}>p\tan x$)
$\iff\dfrac{(p-1)^2}3<1\iff -1<\dfrac{p-1}{\sqrt3}<1\iff1-\sqrt3<p<1+\sqrt3$
